# Can't get WordPress' custom image sizes

Tags: wordpress

I defined my custom image sizes like this:

```
  add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_image_size('news-big', 370, 240, true);
    add_image_size('news-small',270,150,true);
    add_image_size('portfolio-big',370,500,true);
    add_image_size('portfolio-small',270,350,true);
    add_image_size('client',200,150,false);
```

I uploaded test photos and it works - they are resized. But when I try to print it:

```
    <?php $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'news-big') ); ?>
    <?php print_r($img); ?>
```

It returns 'thumb' (150x150). It's first time I see something like this. I use Roots framework theme. What's wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a misplaced bracket, so you weren't actually passing a size to `wp_get_attachment_image_src` and it was defaulting to thumbnail.

```
<?php $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'news-big' ); ?>
```

Comment: This isn't even funny, I spent over 30 minutes on Google for this :D Thanks mate! Typos are always the worse ;)

Comment: @TomekBuszewski They are especially frustrating when things are failing silently.  PHP doesn't throw errors for passing in too many parameters.

Comment: I write code like this almost all the time and it was a huge 'wtf' moment for me just back then. Thanks again, you saved my faith in myself ;))

Answer (score 2):

[`get_post_thumbnail_id`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id) takes only one argument, the post id...

You want to pass your size argument to the wp_get_attachment_image_src

```
$img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(
             get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 
             news-big'
           );
```

#### Why?

Even though WordPress makes many images per your size definitions, there is still only a single attachment id.  There are not different ids for the different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong displaying of thumdnail:

```
<?php $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'news-big') ); ?>
<?php print_r($img); ?>
```

If u add thumnail to post u may simple use:

```
the_post_thumbnail();
```

without this all other things. And if u add custome thumbnail size u may use:

```
the_post_thumbnail('news-big');
```

But before use it u must really add image to post as "Featured image".